# Google ADMob Not Displaying Ads

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, admob

Google ADMob only displays ads (fullscreen) when Settings>Privacy>Limit Ad Tracking is turned off. If I turn it on, all fullscreen ads stop displaying. Is there anyway to make it so it displays ads even when limit ad tracking is on?

Comment: According to forums I've read, it doesn't prevent the ads from placing, it prevents the ads from using specific data to target the user. Someone in [This Thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/OGhJdAA1Lz4) mentioned that the ads slowed down for a couple of days before it resumed it's normal pace, maybe that is what has happened for you.

Comment: @Jake I'll keep an eye out for this. Thank you.